# How To Get Alexa Ranking In Java

Tags: java, alexa-internet

I tried to use Java and DOM XML parser to get the Alexa ranking from below :

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=domainName
```

Is there any API for Alexa ranking and other useful for particular URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep but you've gotta pay for it: http://aws.amazon.com/awis/

Comment: Since summer 2015 alexa gives 1000 calls a month for free. Check it out!